# how to pass directive attribute to directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm have this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="param in item.parameters">
    <rating param_item="{{param}}"></rating>
</div>
```

how can i pass the given attribute to the directive template?

Comment: It would be something on these lines http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/FHVD9/ . Also see directive documentation.

Comment: not exactly what i meant..
i don't want the value to come from the ctrl scope, but from
the attribute (in this case "obj")..
if obj containd "World" and you would write {{obj}}  in the 
template it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like creating child scope for element directives:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Dz7fcZaT4KdRDa869rwm?p=preview

```
app.directive('rating', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      paramItem: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr){
      console.log(scope.paramItem);
    }
  }
});
```

There are a couple other ways too, depending on how you expect your directive to work.

Comment: First of all thanx for fast replying,
Second, i can see the code works but for some reason,
it doesn't work on my project.. 

if my directive is inside a ng-repeat (1 or more) can it cause problems?

Comment: Maybe fork and update the plunker to match what you have. Then I can help